# merge on int64 and object columns in text mining

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have 1 DataFrame, I have a problem to combine Dataframe with table because the data type is different, I have tried to change the datatype but the sum result does not appear

this Dataframe

```
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------              --------------  -----  
 0   content             1200 non-null   object 
 1   remove_lower_punct  1200 non-null   object 
 2   tokenise            1200 non-null   object 
 3   remove_stopwords    1200 non-null   object 
 4   lemmatise           1200 non-null   object 
 5   Topic1              1200 non-null   float64
 6   Topic2              1200 non-null   float64
 7   Topic3              1200 non-null   float64
 8   Topic4              1200 non-null   float64
 9   Topic5              1200 non-null   float64
 10  Dominant_topic      1200 non-null   int64  
 11  sentiment           1200 non-null   object 
 12  sentiment score     1200 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(6), int64(1), object(6)

this table i want combine,table name 'all_topics'  :
    Dominant_topic  topic_name
0   Topic3          [sertifikat vaksin]
1   Topic5          [internet]
2   Topic4          [the app]
3   Topic2          [update malah]
4   Topic1          [user friendly]
```

this my code

```
results = df.groupby(['Dominant_topic', 'sentiment']).count().reset_index()

results = results.merge(all_topics, on='Dominant_topic')
results['topic_name'] = results['topic_name'].apply(', '.join)

graph_results = results[['topic_name', 'sentiment', 'sentiment score']]
graph_results = graph_results.pivot(index='topic_name', columns='sentiment',
                                    values='sentiment score').reset_index()

graph_results.set_index('topic_name', inplace=True)

display(graph_results)
```

Comment: Which column are you trying to add?

Comment: i want combine table with my dataframe

Comment: If you're trying to merge 2 dataframes together you should post a description of both

Comment: Also when you refer to adding/summing that's not the same operation as merging/joining